# How can I force PlayonLinux to use Wine 4?

Tags: ubuntu, wine, playonlinux

PlayOnLinux hasn't been updated since 2015. As such their list of Wine versions are outdated. The highest version available inside the app is `3.2`. The latest wine version available at the time of posting this is 4.

How can I force PlayOnLinux to use Wine 4?

I am using x64 Ubuntu 18.04

EDIT:
I would like to use `PlayOnLinux` so I can use its Microsoft Office installer to install MS office 2016.

Comment: Does it have to be playonlinux? If you are interested to get games working you should have a look at lutris.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it. I was trying to use its MS Office helper to assist with the install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `PlayOnLinux` is outdated is because development of it has moved to a successor project called `Phoenicis PlayOnLinux`. You can find the project site [here](https://phoenicis.org/), and as previously, the [code is open source](https://github.com/PhoenicisOrg/phoenicis).

You will find that the list of wine versions is current and even includes developer releases. I was able to install MS office x86 with any significant issues.

[image]